# No sequence of rv's such that $X_n\overset{P}{\rightarrow}0$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to 2$ and also $\sup\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)<\infty$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, means

> Prove that there is no sequence $(X_n)$ such that $X_n\overset{P}{\rightarrow}0$ and
>   $\mathbb{E}(X_n)\to 2$ and also  $\sup_n\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)<\infty.$

*Attempt.* If we didn't have the last restriction, on $([0,1],\mathcal{B}_{[0,1]},\lambda)$, sequence $X_n:=2n{1}_{[0,1/n]}$ would give $X_n\overset{P}{\rightarrow}0$ and
$\mathbb{E}(X_n)= 2$ (whereas $\sup\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)= +\infty$). Back to the nonexistence part, Markov's inequality: $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>\epsilon)\leqslant \frac{\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)}{\epsilon^2}\leqslant 
\frac{\sup_n\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)}{\epsilon^2}$$
seems compelling to use, but I have not reached a contradiction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that your sequence is uniform integrable in which case it would also coverage in $L_1$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $X_n \to 0$ in probability and $\sup_n \mathbb{E}(X_n^2) < \infty$. Then $\mathbb{E}(X_n) \to 0$.

Indeed, let $\varepsilon >0$ and write
$$
\begin{align}|\mathbb{E}(X_n)| &\leq  \mathbb{E}\left(|X_n| \mathbf{1}_{|X_n| > \varepsilon}\right) + \mathbb{E}\left(|X_n| \mathbf{1}_{|X_n|\leq \varepsilon}\right)\\
&\leq \sqrt{\mathbb E \left(X_n^2\right)\mathbb P\left(|X_n|>\varepsilon\right)}+\varepsilon
\end{align}
$$
where in the last inequality I use Cauchy-Schwarz. The assumptions imply that
$$
\limsup_n \left|\mathbb E (X_n)\right| \leq \limsup_n \sqrt{\mathbb E \left(X_n^2\right)\mathbb P\left(|X_n|>\varepsilon\right)}+\varepsilon = \varepsilon.
$$
Since this is true for every $\varepsilon >0$, letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives $\mathbb{E} (X_n) \to 0$.

---

The above argument is elementary. As suggested in Oliver Diaz's comment, you can also argue that the sequence $(X_n)_n$ is uniformly integrable (as it is bounded in $L^2$) and it converges to $0$ in probability, hence it converges to $0$ in $L^1$.